# data binding angular and polymer dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer, angular-dart

I am not able to pass list to polymer element from angular control

polymer element

hellowworld.html

```dart
<polymer-element name = "hello-world" attributes ="message list">
 <template>
    {{message}}
  <template repeat ="{{item in list}}">
    {{item}}
  </template>
 </template>
<script type="application/dart" src="helloworld.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

helloworld.dart

```dart
@CustomTag("hello-world")
class HelloWorld extends PolymerElement {

  @published String message;
  @published List<String> list;
```

Angular control

```dart
@Controller(selector :"[app-ctrl]", publishAs : "ctrl")
class AppController {
  String message = "polymer angular rocks";
  List<Person> _persons = [];
  List<String> list = ["dsdf","dsf"];
```

Angular polymer data binding

```dart
<div app-ctrl>
    <hello-world message ="{{ctrl.message}}" list ="{{ctrl.list}}"></hello-world>
</div>
```

message is displaying fine on browser,but not list data.

shadow root :

[image]

**Edit :**

Now i am using node bind module and [[]] for binding ,still can't pass List object

```dart
 <div app-ctrl>
        <hello-world message ="[[ctrl.message]]" list ="[[ctrl.list]]"></hello-world>
    </div>
```

Error :

> Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' of
>   'value'.
>   (dart-polymer-elements-with-angular/lib/elements/helloworld/helloworld.dart:10)
>   interpolation: "ng-binding"

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the angular_node_bind package.

See [Angular and Polymer Data Binding, Together!](http://blog.sethladd.com/2014/02/angular-and-polymer-data-binding.html)

add the dependency to pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies: 
  angular_node_bind: any
```

init Angular inside `Polymer.run()`

```dart
void main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
    //ngBootstrap(module: new NodeBindModule());
    applicationFactory().addModule(new AppModule()).addMdoule(new NodeBindModule()).run();
  });
}
```

use double square brackets for binding expressions

```dart
<my-element message="[[cool]]"></my-element>
```

The source code of the `angular_node_bind` package also contains an example

Comment: when i used NodeBindModule ,applicationFactory().addModule(new AppModule()).addModule(new NodeBindModule()).run(); ,I am getting following error Internal error: 'package:angular_node_bind/angular_node_bind.dart': malformed type: line 42 pos 2: type 'NgDirective' is not loaded
@NgDirective(selector: r'[*=/\[\[.*\]\]/]')
 ^

Comment: Can you please file an issue in the angular_node_bind packags? I guess it is not updated to the most recent AngularDart version.

Comment: Ok, I fixed angular_node_bind for the latest Angular.dart. Thanks @invariant!

Comment: @JustinFagnani now 'NgDirective' is not loaded error gone ,but i am still not able to pass list object ...

Comment: It is possible to pass objects to the polymer element from the angular repeat template?

Comment: I guess so. Have you tried it? Did you get an error?

Comment: I'm getting this exception: Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Person' of 'value'. Person is the object of my model. Maybe it is better to open a specific Question in SO?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be better to create a new question.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807193/object-binding-between-angular-and-polymer-in-dart