# Object binding between Angular and Polymer in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I'm trying to bind an object from an Angular controlled element to a Polymer element in Dart.

The object to bind:

```dart
class Person {
  String name;
  String surname;

  Person(this.name, this.surname);
}
```

The polymer element template:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="person-element">
  <template>
    <style>
     .label {font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
    <p>
      <span class="label">Name: </span>{{person.name}}
      <span class="label">Surname: </span>{{person.surname}}
    </p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="person_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The polymer element code:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'person.dart';

@CustomTag('person-element')
class PersonElement extends PolymerElement {
  @published Person person;

  PersonElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

In Angular I've created a controller and a module:

```dart
@Controller(
    selector: '[person-container]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl')
class PersonController { 
  List<Person> persons = [new Person('John','Smith'), new Person('Mario','Rossi')];
}

class PersonModule extends Module {
  PersonModule() {
    bind(PersonController);
  }
}
```

The **first solution** tried is using the [angular_node_bind](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_node_bind) package:

```dart
<div person-container ng-cloak>
  <h2>Person elements</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="person in ctrl.persons">
    <div>{{person.name}}</div>
    <person-element person="[[person]]"></person-element>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run the application in Dartium I get this error:

```dart
Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Person' of 'value'. (http://localhost:8080/person_element.dart:6)
```

I've also tried to modify the attribute instantiation in the html code in this way:

```dart
<person-element person=[[person]]></person-element>
```

But I get the same exception.

The angular_node_bind package supports the object binding?

The **second solution** is using the [new binding features of Angular 0.14.0](http://blog.angulardart.org/2014/08/angulardart-0140-symbiotic-meerkat-is.html) and binding the polymer element in this way:

With this solution I don't get any exception, the element is visualized but the fields are empty and the person instance null.

The complete example is here: https://github.com/fedy2/dart-angular-polymer-object-data-binding

Answer (score 1):

The new version of AngularDart (0.14.0) has a support for Polymer-Dart binding (http://blog.angulardart.org).
At the moment there can be some problems with different versions:
[Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies... Incompatible version constraints on code_transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691686/pub-get-failed-1-resolving-dependencies-incompatible-version-constraints-o/25691910#25691910)

Comment: I've tried it using the polymer element in this way: <person-element person="person"></person-element> obtaining the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples at

- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/1461/files
- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/tree/master/example/web

  - https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/paper.html
  - https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/paper.dart
  - https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/paper_radio_group.html
  - https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/paper_radio_group.dart

also have a look at the same files in the `sept15-prg` branch.

the new syntax seems to be like

```dart
<person-element bind-person="person"></person-element>
```

It is possible that the released Angular version doesn't yet support some things used by this examples.

Comment: The paper examples in the https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/ folder use the installed paper elements installed through bower under the bower_components folder. Can I use the same components from paper_elements package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/paper_elements)?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I guess not. You can try to use the elements from this `paper_elements` package from the `src/some-element` subfolders. This are the original JS paper-elements.